# Prove that the number of pairs of positive integers $x, y$ satisfying $(x,y)=g$ and $[x,y]=l$ is $2^k$ if $g \mid l$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let positive integers $g$ and $l$ be given with $g|l$. Prove that the number of pairs of positive integers $x$, $y$ satisfying $(x,y)=g$ and $[x,y]=l$ is $2^k$, where $k$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $l/g$.

I've tried wrinting $x=\prod p^{\alpha (p)}$ and  $y=\prod p^{\beta (p)}$. The task then is finding the numbers of pairs of $x$ and $y$ such that $g=\prod p^{min(\alpha (p),\beta (p))}$ and $l=ag=\prod p^{max(\alpha (p),\beta (p))}$, where $a$ is a positive integer lesser than $g$ and $k$ is the number of prime factors of $a$. I was able to conclude that $a=\prod p^{|\alpha (p)-\beta (p)|}$ but then I got stuck. I'd be glad with a solution or a hint.

Comment: Hint: Prove the case of $g=1$ first.

Comment: The fact that there are $2^k$ should remind you of the number of subsets of a set with $k$ elements.

Comment: It does, but I coudn't think in a way to use this idea.

Answer (score 2):

I would prove it first for $g$ and $l$ having only one prime factor, so $x=p^a, y=p^b$ with $p$ prime.  Since we must have $l=[x,y]=\max(x,y)$ one of them must be $l$.  Similarly, one of them must be $g$.  We have $k=1, 2^k=2$ and we have shown there are exactly two pairs, $(g,l)$ and $(l,g)$.  Now for $k$ primes, the power of the prime dividing $l$ must divide $x$ or $y$ and the power of the prime dividing $g$ must be the power dividing the other.  Select a subset of the primes to be the ones with the higher power dividing $x$.